# How do I get a method to return true in an if statement

Tags: java

```
public boolean occursInBox(int digit, int[][] box) 
{
    //complete this method
    if (digit > 0 && digit > 9)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            {
                if(box[row][col] == digit)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}



public boolean occursInBox(int digit, int row, int column) 
{
    //complete this method

    int boxRow = (row/3);
    int boxCol = (column/3);

        if (occursInBox(digit, getBox(boxRow, boxCol) == true))
        {
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```

I want the if statement to go through only if the method put in the if statement is true but it says the types are incomparable int[][] and Boolean. The method in the if statement is taking the first occursInBox method and it should be able to accept a Boolean variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (occursInBox(digit, getBox(boxRow, boxCol) == true))
```

should be

```
if (occursInBox(digit, getBox(boxRow, boxCol)) == true)
```

or even better

```
if (occursInBox(digit, getBox(boxRow, boxCol)))
```

Comment: Also the whole method could just `return occursInBox(digit, getBox(boxRow/3, boxCol/3));` .

Comment: And `if (digit > 0 && digit > 9)` could be replaced by `if (digit > 9)` (or `if (digit >= 0 && digit <= 9)`, as I suspect you mean).